# How do I create a pseudo file in bash that appends to another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a closed program (namely Intersystems 'csession' Cachédb terminal) that will write to a file given as a parameter. It do so several times, as then returns. Each time, the given file is overwritten, so at the end, I only get the last result...

I had the idea that it might be possible to trick and give a special pseudo-file as a parameter, that would act as a proxy and append what is written into it into another file.

```
create proxyfile as >> realfile
cat "Hello" > proxyfile
cat "Bye" > proxyfile
cat realfile
Hello
Bye
```

Does anyone think this might be doable, possibly using a little utility ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a FIFO file (named pipe) for this purpose. To see how they work, open up two terminal windows. In one, do

```
cd /tmp
mkfifo pipe
tail -f pipe
```

and in the other

```
cd /tmp
echo "Hello" > pipe
echo "Bye" > pipe
```

For the actual problem, let your application write to the FIFO and use `tail -f pipe > outputfile` in the background to gather the results into `outputfile`.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was hopping for! Thanks. (note for compeltness, it does not work with csession... I guess CacheDB tries to handle the file given as a parameter in a specific way that does not fit into standard Unix schemes... I'll open a bug report on the subject).

Comment: @alci: then it probably unlinks the file before opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/dev/stdout` as output file, pipe it to cat and append standard ouput to a file with `>>`

```
csession /dev/stdout | cat >>realfile
```

This will not overwrite, but append to the existing file.

Comment: "that will write to a file given as a parameter" -- so the OP isn't redirecting stdout.

Comment: Why do you use `| cat >>realfile` instead of `>>realfile`? Also @larsmans writing to `/dev/stdout` is like redirecting to stdout.

Comment: @bfontaine When you use `csession /dev/stdout >>realfile`, then the program will truncate `realfile` instead of appending to it. This would be the same as `csession realfile`.